# Writing different .csv files based on different value and column combinations in R

Tags: r, iteration, purrr

I want to write different .csv files based on a value and column combination. A sample tbl can be found below:

```
# libs 
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table) 

# tbl
tbl <- tibble(
  Record = 1:100,
  B1     = c(rep("B1", 10), rep(NA, 90)),
  B2     = c(rep("B2", 20), rep(NA, 80)),
  B3     = c(rep("B3", 40), rep(NA, 60)),
  B4     = c(rep("B4", 70), rep(NA, 30)),
  B5     = c(rep("B5", 95), rep(NA, 5))
)

tbl
```

Writing different csv files one by one would be done like this:

```
B1 <- tbl %>%
  filter(B1 == "B1") %>% 
  select(Record, B1) %>% 

  fwrite(., file = "B1.csv")
```

However, I want to iterate this process by making a custom function and writing the different .csv files one by one for each value column combination. I tried something like this below.

```
Batch <- "B1"
f_stack <- function(Batch) {

  batch <- tbl %>%
    filter(Batch == Batch) %>% 
    select(Record, Batch)

  return(batch)

}

f_stack(Batch)
```

However, it doesn't filter the correct records. I left out the `fwrite` line of code, because it doesn't return the right tbl. Does someone know how to pull this of (preferably with `purrr`) Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I think because you keep repeating `Batch` in different contexts, it messes up the way the filter works. By using `get(Batch)` you make sure that it's comparing the vector to your string, and not the string to itself.

```
tbl %>%
     filter(get(Batch) == Batch) %>% 
     select(Record, Batch)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Record B1   
    <int> <chr>
 1      1 B1   
 2      2 B1   
 3      3 B1   
 4      4 B1   
 5      5 B1   
 6      6 B1   
 7      7 B1   
 8      8 B1   
 9      9 B1   
10     10 B1
```

But an even simpler solution would be to skip the function altogether and use a `lapply` on a vector of the column names you're interested in:

```
Batch<-c("B1","B2","B3")
lapply(Batch, function(x) {filter(tbl,get(x)==x) %>%
    select(Record, x) %>% 
    fwrite(., file = paste0(x,".csv"))})
```

(note that this will return a list of `NULL`s, because the function doesn't actually return anything at the end. If you want a list of the individual dataframes, that's easy to do too)

Comment: The `get()` did the trick! I wasn't aware of the function, thanks! Answer has been accepted. With respect with your second answer: I think you have missed a second `)` after fwrite, but It might be better to skip the function altogether indeed.

Comment: Yes, I did miss that extra `)`... sorry about that. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply(1:5,function(x){
  z<-paste0("B",x)
  write.csv(tbl[tbl[[z]]==z&!is.na(tbl[[z]]),"Record"],file=paste0(z,".csv"))
})

read.csv("B1.csv")

#    X Record
#1   1      1
#2   2      2
#3   3      3
#4   4      4
#5   5      5
#6   6      6
#7   7      7
#8   8      8
#9   9      9
#10 10     10
```